# Print Excel Sheet in NPOI

Tags: wpf, printing, npoi

I am using NPOI in wpf project To write an excel File
I want to print it directly into landscape A4 After that, that means I want to write the excel and printit correctly Directly , How to do that,I tried flowDocument and print Dialog but the result was bad,  thanks alot